# Download with rsync through bastion/jumper, without .ssh/config changes

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'd like to download a file from server C, through server B (bastion) to my local server A.

Normally I'd handle the mess in ssh/config with `ProxyCommand`, but in this case I can't. Can we make a one-liner with rsync which still would allow me to do the above?

Answer (score 6):

This is quite the one-liner, but you can do the following:

```
 rsync -e 'ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@B"' user@C:file .
```

Comment: In newer versions of ssh, you can also use the `-J` ssh command-line argument to make a shorter and more readable command: `rsync -e 'ssh -J user@B' user@C:file .`

Comment: @theferrit32 that's a proper answer on its own. If you make it an answer I'll accept it in favor of my own

Comment: o.c. I meant to say, "I'll unaccept my answer, in favor of **your answer**"